# gem5 simulator failed install, how to install properly and use for ARM simulations

Tags: gem5

this is my first time trying gem5 and I can't seem to install it properly. I tried these sources:

http://www.m5sim.org/Download

http://www.m5sim.org/Introduction

and these commands:

```
sudo apt-get install mercurial scons swig gcc m4 python python-dev libgoogle-perftools- dev g++
hg clone http://repo.gem5.org/gem5
cd gem5/
scons build/ARM/gem5.opt -j2
build/ARM/gem5.opt configs/example/se.py -c tests/test-progs/hello/bin/arm/linux/hello
```

but I get error from `hg clone` that is `abort: error: Name or service not know` and when I try to build it I get

[image: ``]

Even though I have installed `protobuf`.

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 in VM. I am asking for guide to install it and to set it up for ARM simulation, any sites/documentaries/steps will be helpful.

Comment: `git clone https://github.com/gem5/gem5.git` ........ Requires : `sudo apt install g++ scons swig protobuf-c-compiler golang-goprotobuf-dev libprotobuf-c-dev libprotobuf-dev libhdf5-dev libpng-dev ruby-dev libgoogle-perftools-dev valgrind`

Comment: Thanks, I think I manage do start gem5 but I got `collect2: fatal error: id terminated with signal 9 [Killed] compilation terminate.`

Comment: »compilation terminate« : Which command caused it ?? .....  The command `build/ARM/gem5.opt configs/example/se.py -c tests/test-progs/hello/bin/arm/linux/hello` works OK here : `Hello world!`

Comment: compilation terminate was caused from `scons build/ARM/gem5.opt -j2`

Comment: The build command is `scons build/ARM/gem5.opt`, not -j2 . ..... I had two builds of  "gem5", Ubuntu 20.04 + Debian 11, and another Ubuntu 20.04 computer just did a gem5 build. ... Can't fail ....... 'gem5' is python : May be you are missing basic python tools like  `sudo apt install python3-dev python-dev-is-python2 python-setuptools`

Comment: @KnudLarsen Yes thank you very mush, now it compiles and it runs the command: `Hello world!`

Comment: @KnudLarsen I am also facing the same issue. Not able to build, I am using the following command scons build/RISCV/gem5.opt -j2. But getting a warning message: 
collect2: fatal error: ld terminated with signal 9 [Killed]
compilation terminated.
scons: *** [build/RISCV/gem5.opt] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
*** Summary of Warnings ***
Warning: Deprecated namespaces are not supported by this compiler.
         Please make sure to check the mailing list for deprecation
         announcements.

Can you please help

Comment: @mable george : Unknown OS. Name and version, please. ........ And I can test with your command `scons build/RISCV/gem5.opt` .... ( Not e.g. **-j2**. see above comment, Dec 19.)

Comment: @KnudLarsen I am using 20.04 ubuntu OS. I did the all necessary installation sudo apt install g++ scons swig protobuf-c-compiler golang-goprotobuf-dev libprotobuf-c-dev libprotobuf-dev libhdf5-dev libpng-dev ruby-dev libgoogle-perftools-dev valgrind.  
 I am using virtualbox 6.1. 
I tried scons build/RISCV/gem5.opt as well, but same error.

Comment: Other simulator(s) have failed with VirtualBox (and wmWare). Building a "hardware simulator" = gem5 in another "Virtual hardware simulator" such as VirtualBox may not be possible. Suggest : Install Ubuntu 20.04 into an USB stick. Then gem5 is guarantied to work. Note: gem5 fails with Ubuntu 22.04 .

Comment: Another thing : gem5 is a python app → Please don't forget to install `python3-dev`

Comment: @KnudLarsen Thanks for your help, it worked after installing Ubuntu