# Warning while compling Gem5

Tags: linux, compilation, warnings, gem5

i am trying to compile gem5 on ubuntu 20.04 OS using below command:

scons build/X86/gem5.opt -j8

i got below warning:
Warning: Header file <png.h> not found.
This host has no libpng library.
Disabling support for PNG framebuffers.
Warning: Deprecated namespaces are not supported by this compiler.
Please make sure to check the mailing list for deprecation
announcements.
Warning: Couldn't find HDF5 C++ libraries. Disabling HDF5 support

i tried below solutions:

sudo apt-get install libhdf5-dev

sudo apt-get install libpng-dev

then tried to compile gem5 again with same build command, but still getting the same warnings

Comment: Example, Ubuntu 20.04 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70398936/gem5-simulator-failed-install-how-to-install-properly-and-use-for-arm-simulatio

Comment: thank you!.. it was helpful @KnudLarsen.....for the record i removed the whole gem5 file and redo the steps from https://www.gem5.org/getting_started/   with the requirements you mentioned and it worked